# DL4J - Is there a way to restrict the prediction of a model

Tags: deeplearning4j, dl4j, nd4j

I trained a Mnist model with DL4J. When I use this model in inference mode:

```
INDArray prediction = myModel.output(myINDArrayImage);
```

That gives me a prediction in an `INDArray`, it works properly.
The size of this `INDArray` is equal to number of output on my `OutputLayer` model.

Is there a way to restrict prediction to a character base?
i.e. somethings like this:

```
INDArray prediction = myModel.output(myINDArrayImage, charactersPossible);
```

Where `charactersPossible` is the list of possible output indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an INDArray (using Nd4j.create(double[])) with 1.0 for possible characters and 0.0 for not-possible characters.  Then multiply that with the prediction INDArray, and then Nd4j.argMax the result.

Comment: Thx for your response but my model use output Softmax activation so I have only one possibility in my actual prediction.
my model predict value between 0-9 , i want to say him, give me the best prediction to 3/5/6/8/9 characters (for exemple)

Comment: The method I mentioned works exactly for that case.

Comment: Ok i have to change my loss function ! In this case I could use a mask